# GWT SuperDevMode RPC host

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I'm trying to start SuperDevMode the following way. I modified my `index.jsp` page to append a configurable prefix to the `.nocache.js` file. Production config contains an empty prefix, while development config contains something like `http://localhost:9876`. Then I start the server on Tomcat and type `localhost:8080`. GWT starts normally, but when it tries to send an RPC request, it fails, because request goes to `localhost:9876` instead of `localhost:8080`. How can I customize which host should RPC use to send request to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent some time digging into GWT code with Eclipse and debugger, and found, that GWT RPC concatenates the result of `GWT.getModuleBaseURL()` with the value of `@RemoteServiceRelativePath`. Here is the code of the `getModuleBaseURL` method:

```
public static native String getModuleBaseURL() /*-{
  // Check to see if DevModeRedirectHook has set an alternate value.
  // The key should match DevModeRedirectHook.js.
  var key = "__gwtDevModeHook:" + $moduleName + ":moduleBase";
  var global = $wnd || self;
  return global[key] || $moduleBase;
}-*/;
```

I also examined `dev_mode_on.js` and found several occurences of `__gwtDevModeHook`, but none of them contained `moduleBase`. Also `dev_mode_on.js` install all its hooks into `sessionStorage`, while `getModuleBaseURL` reads from `$wnd` (I used debugger and became convinced that `$wnd` = `window`).

So I used the following solution and it worked for me. I simply added the following into my `index.jsp`:

```
<c:if test="${not empty gwtScriptPrefix}">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window["__gwtDevModeHook:MYAPP:moduleBase"] = "MYAPP/";
  </script>
</c:if>
```

just before

```
<script type="text/javascript"
        src="${gwtScriptPrefix}MYAPP/MYAPP.nocache.js">
</script>
```

where the `gwtScriptPrefix` attribute is calculated by `System.getProperty`, and the corresponding system property is set to `localhost:9876/` on the Eclipse running configuration.